# how to pass a dynamic value to url value in the json file for karate

Tags: json, karate

I have json file
{
"id": "#(dynamic_value),
" href": "customer/#(dynamic_value)",
"@type":"customer "
}

here dynamic_value is the value passed from the calling feature file/function

output : id value is getting passed as expected, But for href it's url/customer/dynamic_value

please let me know how to parameterize href in the above json file

customer/*
customer/#(dynamic_value)